# Is it bad practice to change HTML content via visibility rather than Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

We all know that Ajax requests can be very convenient if we want to navigate through a website without having the page to reload every time. But I'm wondering is Ajax even necessary? Let's assume I have a SPA with 3 tabs as my navbar. Each of the tabs should display different content to the body of the page once they get clicked.
What does prevent me of rendering the whole page markup of all three tabs and set each tab body to invisible. Then depending what tab gets clicked I display that tab body and hide the current one (if there).
I understand that this would be very bad in terms of having a clear resource for each tab content, but I wouldn't have that neither with Ajax?
Also let's assume that the body content is not heavy content which can be loaded quickly and doesn't take ages on first load.
Further I would like to add that no POST or additional requests are involved. The user can't interact rather than making GETs to the content.

I hope this makes sense. What's the benefit of Ajax here over just plain show/hide of content with JS?

Comment: Its good practice. Always ask yourself, if it will make pageload faster for the user. Don't preload 20 MiBs of content, though. Here are some more ideas: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules

Comment: bad practice? good practice? neither. it's a decision that you need to make based on your needs, your target audience, and the size of your content.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is for much more than just SPA rendering. That is only a tiny use. What if new content is posted from a user? Well, it can be handled all without a page refresh. How does that update get seen everywhere else, without page refresh? Ajax. To put it simply, rendering everything at once, as you say is all good...until new data comes through. That is still just one reason.

Also, what if a user does not need to view another 'tab'? It is time wasted to render it. So just render it on request.

As you have said in the comment, maybe your specific situation does mean AJAX is of little use. It really isn't a matter of good practice. It is a matter do I need it.

Comment: I agree with your points, but I'm really talking about this specific case that no content is dynamic, and nothing more than get requests are involved.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much content is hidden in the other two tabs. Also, how certain are you that your SPA will be only of 3 tabs? Or that the tabs will contain specific amount of data?

If its just some text and you're certain it wont amount to a lot later on then it might be better off loaded all at once and toggled on click of tab.

Also, make sure img tags aren't assigned the src attribute while hidden as your browser will request it before its needed. Assign the src attribute after clicking on the tab.

So as long as you're certain you have small amounts of data in your tabs, don't need fresh content from server and keep the images from loading before actually viewing the tab I think ajax load isn't necessary. A simple fadeToggle should suffice. It'll result in better user experience.